# NoSuchElement Exception using .format() in xpath Selenium

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

From the website https://icem.data-archive.ac.uk/#step2, I want to check a specific box upon an iteration.
With the following line of code, I am trying to get to click on a checkbox, whose index is entered in the xpath through the .format() command. This doens't work, as I get an nosuchelement exception.

```
   conto = 1 
     count = conto

     while count > 10: #Getting to the correct county page 
          webD_find_element_by_link_text('Next').click()
          count = count - 10

     for i in range(count,11):

          #Clicking correct county
          WebDriverWait(webD, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[{}]/label/input'.format(count)))).click()
```

I suspect this error comes from the fact the element is in a pop up window, and would need to include a reference to the div id of the pop up window. The line of xpath:

```
'//div[@class="modal-content"]//input[@class="ng.pristine ng.valid"]'
```

returns all the buttons, in a list. How can I use the relative xpath here to select the specific checkbox I need, depending on the index/count?

Code up to this point:

````
import selenium
import time
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException, NoSuchElementException, NoSuchWindowException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

chrome_path = r'C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe'

webD=wd.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path)

webD.get('https://beta.ukdataservice.ac.uk/myaccount')

WebDriverWait(webD, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="myaccount-login"]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div/p/button'))).click()

WebDriverWait(webD, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="username"]'))).send_keys('ukd1217078879')

WebDriverWait(webD, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="password"]'))).send_keys('Census4Me!')

webD.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/div[6]/button').click()

webD.get('https://icem.data-archive.ac.uk/#step1')

#YEARS LOOP BEGINS 

for year in [1851, 1861, 1881, 1891, 1901, 1911]:

     webD.find_element_by_xpath("//b[@class='ng-binding' and text()='{}']/preceding-sibling::input[@type='radio']".format(str(year))).click()

     # Continuing to England & Step 2, Opening Counties Variable, More Variables 

     WebDriverWait(webD, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//b[@id = "country_england"]/preceding-sibling::input'))).click()

     webD.find_element_by_xpath('//html/body/div/section/section[1]/article[2]/div/div/button').click()

     WebDriverWait(webD, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="county_category"]/button[1]'))).click()

     WebDriverWait(webD, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="county_category"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/button'))).click()



# COUNTIES LOOP BEGINS 

     conto = 1 
     count = conto

     while count > 10: #Getting to the correct county page 
          webD_find_element_by_link_text('Next').click()
          count = count - 10

     for i in range(count,11):

          #Clicking correct county
          WebDriverWait(webD, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[{}]/label/input'.format(count)))).click()                           
          #Adding 1 to absolute count, conto 
          conto = conto + 1
          #Store variables 
#          county_text = webD.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[{}]/label'.format(count)).text

#          county_pop = int(county_text.split("(")[-1].replace(")","").replace(",", ""))

 #         print(county_pop)
          county_pop = 1001000
          #Apply County Selection, open HISCO & More Variables
          WebDriverWait(webD, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(.,'Apply')]"))).click()

          WebDriverWait(webD, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[@class = "ice-allow-download-alert ng-animate ng-hide-remove ng-hide-remove-active"]')))

          WebDriverWait(webD, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[@class = "ice-allow-download-alert ng-animate ng-hide-remove ng-hide-remove-active"]')))

          WebDriverWait(webD, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//b[text()[contains(.,"HISCO classified occupation")]]/..'))).click()

          WebDriverWait(webD, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="workhistoryunit_category"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/button'))).click()

          #HISCO OCCUPATION SELECTION LOOP

          if county_pop < 1000000:
               
               while True:

                    checklist =  webD.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="modal-content"]//input[@class="ng-pristine ng-valid"]')

                    for elem in checklist:
                         elem.click()

                    try:
                         WebDriverWait(webD, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[not(contains(@class, "disabled"))]/a[.="Next"]'))).click()

                    except TimeoutException:

                         webD.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="modal-content"]//div[@class="col-sm-3 text-left visible-xs"]/button').click()
                         


                         
                         #WebDriverWait(webD, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="modal-content"]//div[@class="col-sm-3 text-left visible-xs"]/button'))).click()
                         #WebdriverWit on element induces TOE

                         #button = webD.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="modal-content"]//div[@class="col-sm-3 text-right hidden-xs"]/button')
                         #webD.implicitly_wait(10)
                    #ActionChains(webD).move_to_element(button).click(button).perform()



                         

                         break
                        
          else: #County pop >1m, parse through HISCO OCCUPATIONS
               abcount = 1
               relcount = abcount

               while relcount > 10:
                     
                    webD.find_element_by_link_text('Next').click()
                    relcount = relcount - 10

                         # Next, click correct HISCO Occupation button

               for relcount in range(relcount,11):

                    webD.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[{}]/label/input'.format(relcount)).click()

                 ```
````

Comment: I would suggest please do not use  `Absolute XPATH` use `Relative XPATH`  In future, if any webelement is added/removed, then the absolute xpath changes. So always use Relative xpath.

Comment: @KunduK yes that's what I was thinking. But how can i incorporate the indexing in a relative xpath here? All buttons are the same... This yields all 10 buttons: 
'//div[@class="modal-content"]//input[@class="ng.pristine ng.valid"]'